# Force Windows 10 20H2 install without WSUS?

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-10, wsus

I have enforced Windows Updates using Group Policy for many years now. And the client workstations without fail have installed any critical or important updates per my GP settings. Automatically after-hours.

Now with the Windows 10 feature updates it seems as if these aren't being automatically installed. Currently I've had to walk my users through manually installing 20H2 when they see the system tray prompt. To try to force after-hours automated installs I took a look at using internal WSUS. Although the overhead, sluggishness, and sheer scope of approving/declining, downloading, sync, and disk space seems a lot of hoops to jump through in order to force these feature updates to install like all other ones already do.

Any suggestions how I can bypass local WSUS and define GP for these Windows 10 feature updates?

Answer (score 0):

I re-read the newer Microsoft docs for Windows 10 client Group Policy, and now see the setting. Under Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update > Specify deadline for automatic updates and restarts. So presumably this will force the feature and quality updates to install without requiring local WSUS.